# enum declaration in java

Tags: java, android

I have declared enum function as follows

```
public static enum SHAPE


{
    static
    {
      LINE = new SHAPE("LINE", 3);
      CIRCLE = new SHAPE("CIRCLE", 4);
      TEXT = new SHAPE("TEXT", 5);
      SHAPE[] arrayOfSHAPE = new SHAPE[6];
      arrayOfSHAPE[0] = DRAW;
      arrayOfSHAPE[1] = SQUARE;
      arrayOfSHAPE[2] = TRIANGLE;
      arrayOfSHAPE[3] = LINE;
      arrayOfSHAPE[4] = CIRCLE;
      arrayOfSHAPE[5] = TEXT;
    }
  }
```

but I am getting

```
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block at line4 and getting Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete EnumDeclaration at line1.
```

so please assist me in the declaration of this enum.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public enum SHAPE {


    LINE("LINE", 3),
    CIRCLE("CIRCLE", 4),
    TEXT("TEXT", 5);

    public final String shapeName;
    public final int shapeValue;
    public static final SHAPE[] arrayOfShap = values();

    static {
        // This is used to do some operations on enum generally like creating a map of this enums. 
    }

    SHAPE(String name, int value){
        this.shapeName = name;
        this.shapeValue = value;
    }

    // Here one can define static methods to get enum values from arrays, map etc....
}
```

Your required solution can be this or similar.

For more references check below links...

[java example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

& [For static block with enum](http://www.canoo.com/blog/2010/09/24/beautiful-java-enums/)

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple problems with your enum declaration:

1. The static in the enum declaraction doesn't make any sense and causes a compile error.
2. You need to define the values of the enum at the begining of the class (see below).
3. The array declaration should be outside of the static block

This should work, I also cleared up the code a little:

```
public enum Shape {
    LINE("LINE", 3),
    CIRCLE("CIRCLE", 4),
    TEXT("TEXT", 5),
    // DRAW, SQUaRE, TRIANGLE, ...
    ;

    public static final Shape[] SHAPES= new Shape[6];

    static
    {
      SHAPES[0] = DRAW;
      SHAPES[1] = SQUARE;
      SHAPES[2] = TRIANGLE;
      SHAPES[3] = LINE;
      SHAPES[4] = CIRCLE;
      SHAPES[5] = TEXT;
    }

    // Constructor etc.
}
```

I think you don't need the SHAPES-array because you can access all values of the enum by calling: `Shape.values()`

Answer (score 3):

The enum in java is this:

```
public enum SHAPE {

      LINE("LINE", 3),
      CIRCLE("CIRCLE", 4),
      TEXT("TEXT", 5);

      private String type;
      private Integer id;

      SHAPE(String type,Integer id){
        this.type= type;
        this.id = id;  
      }    

      // Getters for type and id 


}
```

Comment: Hi I have declared as follows public static enum SHAPE {
      LINE("LINE", 3),
      CIRCLE("CIRCLE", 4),
      TEXT("TEXT", 5);
      private String type;
      private Integer id;
      SHAPE(String type,Integer id){
        this.type= type;
        this.id = id;  
      }    
      SHAPE[] arrayOfSHAPE = new SHAPE[6],
      arrayOfSHAPE[0] = DRAW,
      arrayOfSHAPE[1] = SQUARE,
      arrayOfSHAPE[2] = TRIANGLE,
      arrayOfSHAPE[3] = LINE,
      arrayOfSHAPE[4] = CIRCLE,
      arrayOfSHAPE[5] = TEXT;} Syntax error on token "0", delete this token error at arrayOfSHAPE[0] = DRAW,

Comment: In addition to @Sergio's answer , use SHAPE.values() to iterate over the enum values and also use primitive "int" instead of the wrapper Integer

Comment: I have added getter function.public Integer getId() {
        return id;
      }  How to iterate I don't know.How will I get th evalues

Comment: for(SHAPE s : SHAPE.values()){
 // Use variable s here like s.getId() or s.getType() 
}

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I do not know what you are trying todo. But as per `enum` declaration, you haven't specified any instance (its empty).

```
public enum SHAPE
{
;//define a seperator where one declares instances.
static
{
  SHAPE LINE = new SHAPE("LINE", 3);
  SHAPE CIRCLE = new SHAPE("CIRCLE", 4);
  SHAPE TEXT = new SHAPE("TEXT", 5);
  SHAPE[] arrayOfSHAPE = new SHAPE[6];
  arrayOfSHAPE[0] = DRAW;
  arrayOfSHAPE[1] = SQUARE;
  arrayOfSHAPE[2] = TRIANGLE;
  arrayOfSHAPE[3] = LINE;
  arrayOfSHAPE[4] = CIRCLE;
  arrayOfSHAPE[5] = TEXT;
 }
}
```

And `enum` class declaration cannot be static. You should be doing as Sergio mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Use comma separator

```
public static enum SHAPE
{
    static
    {
      LINE = new SHAPE("LINE", 3),
      CIRCLE = new SHAPE("CIRCLE", 4),
      TEXT = new SHAPE("TEXT", 5),
      SHAPE[] arrayOfSHAPE = new SHAPE[6],
      arrayOfSHAPE[0] = DRAW,
      arrayOfSHAPE[1] = SQUARE,
      arrayOfSHAPE[2] = TRIANGLE,
      arrayOfSHAPE[3] = LINE,
      arrayOfSHAPE[4] = CIRCLE,
      arrayOfSHAPE[5] = TEXT
    }
}
```